# Recursive Graph Traversal

Tags: java, graph, path, traversal, depth-first-search

---

I'm writing a program in Java to solve puzzles from this game: 
http://universefactory.net/0/

I've modeled the problem as follows

Node Class:

```
 package model;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Node {
    private final int nodeId;
    private ArrayList<Edge> edges;

    ArrayList<Edge> getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    public int getNodeId() {
        return nodeId;
    }

    public Node(int id) {
        nodeId = id;
        edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Node() {
        nodeId = -1;
    }

    private void addEdge(Edge toBeAdded) {

        if (toBeAdded != null)
            edges.add(toBeAdded);
    }

    public void addEdgeTo(Node to, Star star) {
        if(this.equals(to))
            return;
        if (to != null) {
            Edge edge = new Edge(to, star);
            addEdge(edge);
        }

    }

    public void addEdgeTo(Node to) {
        if(this.equals(to))
            return;
        if (to != null) {
            Edge edge = new Edge(to);
            addEdge(edge);
        }

    }

    public Edge getEdge(Node to)
    {
        Node edgeDestination;
        for(Edge edgeIterator: edges)
        {
            edgeDestination = edgeIterator.goesTo();
            if(edgeDestination.equals(to))
                return edgeIterator;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Edge popEdge(Node to)
    {

        Node edgeDestination;
        for(Edge edgeIterator: edges)
        {
            edgeDestination = edgeIterator.goesTo();
            if(edgeDestination.equals(to))
            {
                edges.remove(edgeIterator);
                return edgeIterator;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (nodeId != other.nodeId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Edge class:

```
 package model;

    public class Edge {

    private final Star star;
    private final Node to;

    Edge(Node nodeTo) {
        star = null;
        to = nodeTo;
    }

    Edge(Node nodeTo, Star star) {
        this.star = star;
        to = nodeTo;
    }

    public void consumeEdge() {
        if (star != null) {
            star.die();
        }
    }

    public boolean consumable() {
        if (star == null)
            return false;
        return star.isAlive();
    }

    public Node goesTo() {
        return to;
    }
    }
```

Star Class

```
 package model;

    public class Star {

    boolean dead = false;
    public void die() {
        dead = true;
    }

    public boolean isAlive()
    {
        return !dead; 
    }
    }
```

and Graph Class:

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Graph {

private ArrayList<Node> nodes = null;
private ArrayList<Star> stars = null;
private Node startNode = null;
private final int startNodeID = 0;

public Graph(ArrayList<Node> nodeArr, ArrayList<Star> starArr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    nodes = nodeArr;
    stars = starArr;
    setStartNode();
}

private void setStartNode() {
    for (Node nodeIterator : nodes) {
        if (nodeIterator.getNodeId() == startNodeID) {
            startNode = nodeIterator;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public Graph(Graph other) {

    nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    stars = new ArrayList<Star>();
    nodes.addAll(other.getNodes());
    stars.addAll(other.getStars());
    setStartNode();
}

public ArrayList<Node> solve() {

    final int numberOfStars = stars.size();
    ArrayList<Node> solution = new ArrayList<Node>();
    solution.add(startNode);
    recursiveSolver(startNode, numberOfStars, solution);
    return solution;
}

private boolean recursiveSolver(Node currentNode, int numberOfStars,
        ArrayList<Node> solutionPointer) {

    if (numberOfStars == 0) 
        return true;
    for(Edge edgeIterator: currentNode.getEdges())
    {
        Node nextNode = edgeIterator.goesTo();
        Graph deepCopy = new Graph(this);
        currentNode = deepCopy.getNode(currentNode);
        nextNode = deepCopy.getNode(nextNode);
        //deepCopy.traverse(currentNode, nextNode);
                    //deepCopy.recursiveSolver(.....);
        //Not sure how to finish this <---------------------------PROBLEM AREA
    }


}

private Node getNode(Node currentNode) {
    return getNode(currentNode.getNodeId());

}

private ArrayList<Node> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}

private ArrayList<Star> getStars() {
    return stars;
}

public void linkNodesWith(int fromNodeID, int toNodeID, Star star) {

    final Node from = getNode(fromNodeID);
    final Node to = getNode(toNodeID);
    if (from != null && to != null)
        linkNodesWith(from, to, star);

}

private void linkNodesWith(Node nodeFrom, Node nodeTo, Star star) {
    nodeFrom.addEdgeTo(nodeTo, star);
    nodeTo.addEdgeTo(nodeFrom, star);

}

public Node getNode(int nodeId) {

    for (Node iteratorNode : nodes) {
        if (iteratorNode.getNodeId() == nodeId)
            return iteratorNode;
    }
    return null;
}

public void removeNode(Node nodeToRemove) {
    nodes.remove(nodeToRemove);
    for (Node nodeIterator : nodes) {
        nodeIterator.popEdge(nodeToRemove);
    }
}

public void removeNode(int nodeIdToRemove) {
    Node nodeToRemove = getNode(nodeIdToRemove);
    removeNode(nodeToRemove);
}

    //Last three functions are used to create a specific graph to solve
public void populateEdges() {
    for (Node nodeFromIterator : nodes) {
        for (Node nodeToIterator : nodes) {
            nodeFromIterator.addEdgeTo(nodeToIterator);
        }
    }
}

public void replaceEdge(int nodeFromID, int nodeToID, Star star) {
    Node nodeFrom = getNode(nodeFromID);
    Node nodeTo = getNode(nodeToID);
    unlinkNodes(nodeFrom, nodeTo);
    linkNodesWith(nodeFrom, nodeTo, star);

}

private void unlinkNodes(Node nodeFrom, Node nodeTo) {
    nodeFrom.popEdge(nodeTo);
    nodeTo.popEdge(nodeFrom);
}
}
```

I can't figure out a way to solve this without making deep copies of the graph every time a node is deleted/traversed, and even then am not sure as to how I can save the path in an array-list. Is there a better way to model the problem that would simplify the solution?

universefactory.net/0 : the game im trying to write a solution for.

Comment: I don't understand how you come to the conclusion that you must modify the graph. Solving this is a simple backtracking application. Any changing state can be stored in a stack that you pass along or you can temporarily modify the nodes to mark them as visited. That said, please indent your code if you want people to read it!

Comment: I didn't conclude that, It's just that I don't know how to without modifying the graph. Could you please point me to an example?

Comment: Search the web for "backtracking".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive backtracking solution and an immutable graph, for example

1) Construct a graph of all nodes + all edges and a list of stars (each star containing a list of all edges it is on, OR each edge containing a list of references to stars (not copies) that are on its path. Whatever makes more sense to you)

2) Write a recursive method. Its parameters will be:

- the graph + list of stars (immutable)
- the list of nodes taken so far, in order
- the list of edges taken so far, in order
- the list of stars left to take

It should do the following:

2a) If it has possible moves to take (edges from the node it's on that aren't in the list of edges taken so far), recursively branch and try each of those next moves, by calling itself with

- the graph + list of stars (immutable)
- a copy of the list of edges taken so far, in order, adding the new edge taken by this mode
- a copy of the list of nodes taken so far, in order, adding the new node taken by this mode
- a copy of the list of stars left to take, subtracting new stars taken by this move

2b) If it has no possible modes to take, check if we have taken all stars. If we have, then this is the solution (print out the list of edges taken)